# Windows Task Scheduler trigger on event, but only once a day

Tags: scheduled-tasks

on Windows 7, how do I trigger on first occurance of an event each day to run a small batch file?

I'm trying to kick off a small batch script that runs only for a few seconds when I unlock my PC, but I only want it to run the first time I unlock my PC and never again until the I unlock my PC after 12AM of the next day. I can't tigger on specific time because the time at which I unlock my PC is random. I have been playing with task scheduler for days without success.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the script set a state on first run, which keeps it from running again, for example by exiting immediately instead of doing anything when the state is set.
Then set up a task that triggers on log on to execute said script and another task that runs each day at 12AM to unset/remove the state set by the script. This should give you the effect you want.

A better solution, would be to have the script deactivate (f.e. via schtasks) the task triggered by logging on that called it and have the 12AM task restart the logon triggered task once each day.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem, so here is my workaround without knowing to much scripting:

I created 4 .bat-files containing basically the following.

1. start application, afterwards replace bat-file1 with bat-file2
2. do nothing
3. replace bat-file1 with bat-file4
4. start application, afterwards replace bat-file1 with bat-file2

Now I created to scheduled tasks:
The first one runs every day at 12am and runs batch-file 3. Hence, it replaces bat-file1 with bat-file4.
The second one runs after every unlocking of the computer and runs batch-file1.

As you can see in total it does exactly what you want, although it might be a little bit complicated...
On your first unlock it starts your desired script and replaces itself with a dummyfile (the batch file only contains the word `exit`). After every following unlocking nothing but a hardly noticable cmd popup happens.
At 12am the dummyfile is replaced by the initial batch-file again, to provide your task in the next morning.